# MongoDB find() query in expressjs returning an empty result on second run

Tags: express, mongodb-query

I'm having the following issue:

I have an express server that I use as the backend / "API" for a website I'm building.

I have the route /weekly that supports 2 parameters: start and end time

When no parameters are given I generate unix timestamps of the current day at 11.59 PM and the day 3 weeks prior at 1 am

with these 2 timestamps and the database object I run this function:

```
weeklyimport: async function (db_payload, start, ende) {
db = db_payload
let callection = await db.collection('History').find({$and: [
    {"datumUnix": {$gt: start}}, {"datumUnix": {$lt: ende}}, {"status": 4}, {"bereich": {$ne: "Akquise"}}, {"bereich": {$ne: "Entwicklung"}}, {"bereich": {$ne: "Gewinnung"}}
    ]}).toArray()
return callection
}
```

Upon first load of the page I call the page without parameters to get the data  for the timespan of 21 days. Console.log for start and end of the first query (without params) shows 1550530800 for start and 1552382360 for end. this query returns ~6800 results.
After changing the timeframe to the same start and end (just manually and not automatically this time) the start and end change to 1550530800 and 1552431599 respectively. This time however I get an empty array as the return and a count of 0 results.

When I run

```
db.getCollection('History').find({$and: [
        {"datumUnix": {$gt: 1550530800}}, {"datumUnix": {$lt: 1552431599}}, {"status": 4}, {"bereich": {$ne: "Akquise"}}, {"bereich": {$ne: "Entwicklung"}}, {"bereich": {$ne: "Gewinnung"}}
    ]}).count()
```

in Robo 3T i get 6835 results with the exact same query that returned an empty array before. Response time for this query was ~0.248s, so it shouldn't be a timeout issue.

I logged the start and end everywhere to make sure they are passed on correctly, and they are. My biggest issue (apart from the empty array) is that I dont get any errors at all when running this. I have done pretty much the same in another function and that works without an issue.

Any advice on what might cause this is greatly appreciated. Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution - the dates passed onto the 2nd query were treated as strings and not integers. parseInt() solved the issue